# Sending 50+ messages causing issues lead to generic failure

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I am developing an application in which i need to send 100+ of messages. After going through few threads i came to know there is limitation on sending messages like 100 messages can be send in an hour. To do so i divide my recipient list into chunks and place delay of 5 seconds between each chunk and 3 seconds delay in every message. The delay between chunks increase after every chunk and when it gets to 100 seconds it will reset to 5 seconds. After that it worked OK for 50 messages but when i raise recipient list it causing issues some messages didn't go at first place and shown as error messages in native.

Is there any standard way to achieve this i may need to send 100+ messages , how can i send multiple messages without any failure at once. If i need to place delay what should be the appropriate delay between chunks or messages.

Thanks in advance.

```
private final int MAX_SMS_IN_ONE_TIME = 10;
private final int DELAY_BETWEEN_CHUNKS = 5000;

public void sendMessage(arguments){ 
    // Send long messages in chunk of 20 messages and put gap of increasing 5 seconds till 50 seconds and then reset.

    final Iterator iterator = messageChunks.iterator();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){

        int interval =1;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            for (final Contact contact :
                (List<Contact>) iterator.next()) {

                sendSMS(body, contact.getmMobileNumbers().get(0));

                App.trackEvent("Message", "Sent", "Messages from our sms app");
            }
        }
        try {
            Log.i("chunk", "chunk # " + interval + " delay is " + DELAY_BETWEEN_CHUNKS);
            Thread.sleep(DELAY_BETWEEN_CHUNKS * interval);
            interval++;
            if (interval == 10) {
                interval = 1;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void sendSMS(final String message, final String phoneNo) {
    try {
        String SENT = "com.ebryx.smscustommessagegeneration"+""+System.currentTimeMillis()+""+((int)this.getmMessageId());
        Intent intentMessageASendStatus = new Intent(SENT);

        final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(App.getContext(),  ((int)this.getmMessageId()),
                intentMessageASendStatus, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        final ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentPI = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(){{add(pi);}};

        App.getContext().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {


                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                        Log.i("tag","sent successfully ");
            break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:

                        Log.i("tag","Generic Failure");
                break;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                        Log.i("tag","No service failure");
            break;

        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:

                        Log.i("tag","Airplane mode failure");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        final SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        final ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts, sentPI, null);

                }}, 3000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you are seeing?

Comment: @ScottNewson , i am not seeing any error message but few messages didnt go due to generic failure.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be no official documentation for SMS send limits, from what I could find and the following site either.

> [Unfortunately](https://frontlinecloud.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/208115703-SMS-sending-limits-with-FrontlineSync-and-Android) there appears to be no public documentation from
>   Google’s Android development team on the issue.

<sup>This is from May 17, 2017</sup>

The only figures on sms limits I've been able to find are from [Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)'s site:

> **[SMS Sending Limitations](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/working-with-sms)**
>   Apps running on Android 1.x and 2.x devices are limited to sending 100 SMS messages an hour, before the
>   user starts getting prompted with each SMS message request to confirm
>   that they do indeed wish to send it.
>
> Apps running on Android 4.x devices, the limits are now 30 SMS
>   messages in 30 minutes .../...

There appears to be no way around increasing that limit [without rooting](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1835056&page=8) the phone. Where you need to change the following settings. The following will allow 1000 SMS to be sent per 180000ms == 30 minutes.

```
SMS_OUTGOING_CHECK_MAX_COUNT 1000
SMS_OUTGOING_CHECK_INTERVAL_MS 1800000
```

The usual (frustrating) Android issues with varying performance across devices also applies. One phone may perform at a different level to another.

This company has determined the maximum SMS capacities for some handsets with their product. [SMS sending limits with FrontlineSync and Android](https://frontlinecloud.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/208115703-SMS-sending-limits-with-FrontlineSync-and-Android). They also advise that rooting the phone may be needed to increase limits.

Related resources:

[Check android package SMS limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802289/check-android-package-sms-limit)

[is there a limit to the number of numbers to send an SMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079151/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-numbers-to-send-an-sms)

[Android Java: How To Send SMS & Receive SMS & Get SMS Messages](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1044639/Android-SMS-MMS-API-Sending-SMS-MMS-Receiving-SMS) dated 30 August, 2017.